# How to query the context so it creates subclassed POCO entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

Say I have the following generated Entity Framework POCO class:

```
public partial class Foo
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

And I subclass it:

```
public class SubclassedFoo : Foo
{
    public override long Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
}
```

How can the ObjectContext retrieve `SubclassedFoo` objects rather than `Foo` objects?

For example, what can I use instead of this?

```
ObservableCollection<Foo> foos = context.Foos
```

as in:

```
ObservableCollection<SubclassedFoo> subclassedFoos = context.???
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but Entity Framework doesn't always play nice with overridden properties. If you get problems with that (even if you don't have problems with it right now), you can change `Id` to a nonvirtual property that calls virtual `getId()` and `setId()` methods, and only override those methods in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Filter with `OfType<SubclassedFoo>`:

```
List<SubclassedFoo> subclassedFoos = context.Foos
    .OfType<SubclassedFoo>()
    .ToList();
```

Or if you really want an `ObservableCollection`:

```
ObservableCollection<SubclassedFoo> subclassedFoos =
    new ObservableCollection<SubclassedFoo>(context.Foos
        .OfType<SubclassedFoo>()
        .AsEnumerable());
```